# Access Label control inside the detailsview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I am trying to set the text of the label control which is inside detailsview but it's not working. But it's showing error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
can anyone guide me please.. ??
My front end code is:

```
<asp:Panel ID="sub_question_panel" runat="server">
   <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" CellPadding="6"    ForeColor="#333333" AutoGenerateRows="false" GridLines="None" >
   <Fields>
      <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
               <table id="Question_view_table">
                  <tr>
<td style="font-family:Arial Rounded MT;">
<label id="Question_no"><span style="font-size:20px;">Question</span>:</label>
<asp:Label ID="Ques_id_label" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height:20px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:18px; ">
<label id="Question_detail"><%# Eval ("Question") %></label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family:'Times New Roman'; font-size:18px;">
<ol style="list-style:upper-alpha">
<li>
<label id="optn1"> &nbsp&nbsp<%# Eval ("Option1") %></label></li>
<li>
<label id="optn2"> &nbsp&nbsp<%# Eval ("Option2") %></label></li>
<li>
<label id="optn3"> &nbsp&nbsp<%# Eval ("Option3") %></label></li>
<li>
<label id="optn4"> &nbsp&nbsp<%# Eval ("Option4") %></label></li>
</ol>
</td>
</tr>
            </table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
</asp:Panel>
```

My back end code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int question_id = 1;
      Label Question_Id = DetailsView1.FindControl("Ques_id_label") as Label;
      Question_Id .Text = Convert.ToString(question_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the **FindControl** for a row, not DataListView

You want to find your label by id, But which one? For each row you have a label with id 'Ques_id_label' . So to find a specific label you must specify the intended row. I did not work with **DataLisView** but I know that it is logically similar to **Asp:Repeater** . To find a control in a row of a Repeater when a command is sent from a row:

```
protected void SaveAnswer(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label Ques_id_label = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Ques_id_label");
```

Which with `e.item` you specify the intended row.

Answer (score 0):

You use FindControl to find `Ques_id_label`, but then reference it normally anyway: `Ques_id_label.Text =`

It should be `Question_Id.Text = Convert.ToString(question_id);`, with the ID you assigned with FindControl.

But did it even compile? Do you use an editor like Visual Studio? Because when I tried your snippet it gave the error `The name 'Ques_id_label' does not exist in the current context`, as it is supposed to.

Comment: I assigned id "Ques_id_label to my label control at front end and yes i also tried Question_Id.Text = Convert.ToString(question_id). I am using visual studio.  Yes when i run it it shows error "object refrence is not set to an object"  and i am also getting a problem the controls which i am assingning inside the DetailsView control the code behind not taking that context..... @VDWWD